# Plotting N-S and E-W Profile of Land Surface Temperature (LST) Across Land Use types in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, profile

I am working on my final year thesis and I need to plot the seasonal North-South and East-West profile of land surface temperature (LST) across various land use types.

I have been able to extract the LST from landsat 7, but I need to plot it using either ArcGIS or if I export the cell LST values into an Excel spreadsheet and plot.